# Missing keyword error in Case when in oracle

Tags: oracle

My select query before changes was:

```
select * from abc
WHERE
    CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc)  = 'CRA' THEN
        CASE WHEN NVL(TRUNC(a.DATEOFSFROM),TO_DATE('99991231','YYYYMMDD')) >= TO_DATE('20170101','YYYYMMDD') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
    When gr.Rgid='021SHOP' THEN
         CASE WHEN TRUNC(a.datep) <= to_date('20190630', 'YYYYMMDD') then 'Y' ELSE 'N' end
    ELSE 'Y' END = 'Y'
```

I need new case when statement,so I added:

```
select * from abc
WHERE
    CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc)  = 'CRA' THEN
        CASE WHEN NVL(TRUNC(a.DATEOFSFROM),TO_DATE('99991231','YYYYMMDD')) >= TO_DATE('20170101','YYYYMMDD') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
    When gr.Rgid='021SHOP' THEN
         CASE WHEN TRUNC(a.datep) <= to_date('20190630', 'YYYYMMDD') then 'Y' ELSE 'N' end
    ELSE 'Y' END = 'Y'
      CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc) IN  ('01FLW','002FE') then
       a.datep <=to_date('20180131', 'YYYYMMDD') END;
```

I added these statement from my side

```
CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc) IN  ('01FLW','002FE') then
           a.datep <=to_date('20180131', 'YYYYMMDD') END;
```

But I am getting error:`ORA-00905:missing keyword` error. I searched these similar question but I only see is case when used is being wrong.But from my analysis,the case when I am using in right.

Comment: Change `ELSE 'Y' END = 'Y'` to just `ELSE 'Y' END` with nothing after the final `END`

Comment: Isn't this just `...WHERE CASE WHEN....END = 'Y'` + `CASE WHEN ...`.? You need to concat multiple conditions with `AND` or `OR` like `CASE WHEN .... END = 'Y' OR CASE WHEN ... END`

Comment: please can u help me writing full query i still tried and got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what exactly should be the outcome so I guessed. Note comments within code, which contains new `CASE`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM abc
 WHERE CASE
          WHEN NVL (gr.Rgid, a.pc) = 'CRA'
          THEN
             CASE
                WHEN NVL (TRUNC (a.DATEOFSFROM),
                          TO_DATE ('99991231', 'YYYYMMDD')) >=
                     TO_DATE ('20170101', 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN
                   'Y'
                ELSE
                   'N'
             END
          WHEN gr.Rgid = '021SHOP'
          THEN
             CASE
                WHEN TRUNC (a.datep) <= TO_DATE ('20190630', 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN
                   'Y'
                ELSE
                   'N'
             END
-- your new WHEN begins here ...                         
          WHEN NVL (gr.Rgid, a.pc) IN ('01FLW', '002FE')
          THEN
             CASE
                WHEN a.datep <= TO_DATE ('20180131', 'YYYYMMDD') 
                THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
             END
-- ... and ends here             
          ELSE
             'Y'
       END =
       'Y'
```

Comment: no brother the case when which I added just needs to compare  a.datep <= TO_DATE ('20180131', 'YYYYMMDD') and only select those data whose a.datep is less than ('20180131', 'YYYYMMDD')

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
select * from abc
WHERE
    CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc)  = 'CRA' THEN
        CASE WHEN NVL(TRUNC(a.DATEOFSFROM),TO_DATE('99991231','YYYYMMDD')) >= TO_DATE('20170101','YYYYMMDD') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
    When gr.Rgid='021SHOP' THEN
         CASE WHEN TRUNC(a.datep) <= to_date('20190630', 'YYYYMMDD') then 'Y' ELSE 'N' end
    ELSE 'Y' END = 'Y'
```

that's all ok.
When adding `CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc) IN  ('01FLW','002FE') then a.datep <=to_date('20180131', 'YYYYMMDD') END` to the end you're screwing up the syntax.
Syntax: `where a = b or c = d`.

You wrote `where a = b` and then added `c` so it becomes `where a = b c`.

Add your new line with a `AND` or `OR` and get a value to compare it to, like

```
SELECT * FROM ABC
WHERE
    CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc)  = 'CRA' THEN
        ...
    ELSE 'Y' END = 'Y'
-- new here
    AND CASE WHEN NVL(gr.Rgid,a.pc) IN  ('01FLW','002FE') AND a.datep <=to_date('20180131', 'YYYYMMDD')
        then 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
    END = 'true';
```

I also transformed your case statement to a equation like `a = b` by moving your condition into the `WHEN`-Block and then comparing if it's the first when block or not by `... END = 'true'`.

You cannot add where statements within a case expression like you did.

Please note that I wrote this without actual verification, so syntac errors may still occur.